# Append to list from dart:typed_data

Tags: list, dart

Dart [typed_data](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/be/dartdoc-viewer/dart:typed_data) library contains few lists (e.g. `Uint8List`, `Uint16List` and so on) which are more efficient than traditional `List` and especially handy when you need to work with binary data. However, all these lists are fixed-size lists, so it is not possible to extend (or append to the list) or shrink the list after it was created. This restriction causes a real issue when the size of resulting list is unknown at the moment of creation.

Consider following example:

```
Uint8List getEven(Uint8List in)
{
    Uint8List out = new Uint8List(0);

    for (num i = 0; i < in.length; ++i)
    {
        if (in[i] % 2 == 0)
            out.add(in[i]); // <- This will throw an exception since Uint8List  is fixed-length
    }

    return out;
}
```

Is there any workaround for this problem, or do I have to use `List<num>` to process binary data, if I need append/resize functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the lists in the build-in `dart:typed_data` library are inmutable.

However, there is an additional [`typed_data`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/typed_data) package on pub that provides [mutable typed data implementations](http://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/typed_data/1.0.0/index.html#typed_data). I think I haven't tried them yet, but I hope they (still) work.

`Uint8Buffer` would be equivalent to the list you are looking for.